# Own removeLastPoint() function for Polygons in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, jquery, gis, openlayers

I'm trying to fix on my application problem with `removeLastPoint()` function from OpenLayers. The problem is that on mobile devices `removeLastPoint()` is removing points on wrong order. On desktop mode everything is working well.

[Here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7308) is the explain of this problem.

Let's me present on images how this "problem with removing points on wrong order" it works in practice.

We're starting from draw some `LineString`:

[image]

We've got now a `LineString` which has been created from connecting of 5th points.
Now I'm trying to call `removeLatPoint()` function by click on my `removeButton`, just like that:

```
removeButton.on('click', () => {
   draw.removeLastPoint(); // this function comes from ol.integration.Draw class
});
```

And now I'm expecting to get result like that:

[image]

but what did I get? I got something like that:

[image]

On the next step I'll get:

[image]

On the next:

[image]

And on the end I'll have got only point number 5.

[image]

The problem is fact that in `OpenLayers` `removeLastPoint()` function is removing not last point but one of before it.

Here is current `removeLastPoint()` function code from `OpenLayers`:

[image]

The problematic is this line for me: `coordinates.splice(-2, 1);` because it is working just like I showed.

[image]

I couldn't wait for official solution of this problem so I wrote my temporary fix of that. On my fix I call before `removeLastPoint()` my own function which is removing last coordinate and is duplicating this coordinate which was before it. Just like that:

[image]

There is once difference. I'm using `draw.extend(measureFeature);` function to duplicate this coordinate before this last, because I have to refresh information which have been saved in private variable `this.sketchCoords_` on the `OpenLayers` site. When I was trying to do it on the other way then `this.sketchCoords_` still remembered previously saved state of drawed geometry and instead of call `removeLastPoint()` for `myArray = ['1','2','3','4','4']` then it was calling for `myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5']`. So I have to use `draw.extend()` to duplicate current last item and update `this.sketchCoords_`.

Here is my own fix on this problem:

```
removeButton.on('click', () => {
    if (this.isMobileDevice) {
        this.removeLastPoint();
    }
    this.draw.removeLastPoint();
}); 

removeLastPoint() {
    let measureFeature = this.sketch;
    measureFeature = measureFeature.clone();
    const geom = measureFeature.getGeometry();

    if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
        const coords = geom.getCoordinates();
        let preparedCoords: [number, number][] = new Array();

        if (coords) {
            preparedCoords = coords;
            preparedCoords.splice(-1, 1);
            geom.setCoordinates(preparedCoords);
            measureFeature.setGeometry(geom);

            if (preparedCoords.length > 0) {
                this.draw.extend(measureFeature);
            }
        }
    } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {

    }
}
```

My fix is working as I exected. After call `removeLastPoint()` is removing redundant item and I've got a correct collection.

And here is starting my real problem. Polygons. On polygons `removeLastPoint()` function doesn't work well too and there we've got this same problem with removing wrong point (not last but before it).

So I'm going to write a similar mechanism to modify polygon coordinates as I wrote for `LineString` geometries.

But how can I update `this.sketchCoords_` by inject my modified coordinates collection if `draw.extend()` is working only for `LineString` geometries?

[image]

I haven't idea how can I do it. Class `Draw` from `OpenLayers` hasn't any helpful function for polygons which will be change or update current drawing polygon.

[Here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Draw-Draw.html#extend) is full of `Draw` class.

Have you got any idea how can I update it and inject my modified coordinate collection?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/presto41/x81L5bgm/) is my fiddle, Maybe it'll helpful. I don't know why but on my fiddle sketch is always null so this fiddle is not working well but it able to show my code a little bit.

Comment: Did you open a ticket for this issue in the official OpenLayers github repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again I solved the problem which I put by myself into StackOverflow. Awesome!

So let me present the solution.

I said that after modify a polygon I need update `this.sketchCoords_` object because without it the `removeLastPoint()` from `OpenLayers` will be working on the old coordinates collection.

If `draw.extend()` is working only for `LineString` geometries then I had to find another solution how to do it.

And I found it.

The solution was:

1. writing own class to extend class Draw from OpenLayers from comes `this.sketchCoords_` object:

   ```
   declare namespace ol { 
      namespace interaction { 
          class ExtendedDrawClass extends ol.interaction.Draw {   
              sketchCoords_?: ol.Coordinate | ol.Coordinate[] | ol.Coordinate[][];
          }
      }
   }
   ```
2. and after that just modify this collection in own code. For example just like that:

   ```
   var myNewCoordinates = geometry.getCoordinates();
   myNewCoordinates.split(-1,1);
   (<ol.Coordinate[][]>(<ol.interaction.ExtendedDrawClass>this.draw).sketchCoords_) = [myNewCoordinates];
   ```

And that's all.

When the code was calling `removeLastPoint()` function from `OpenLayers` then it had a `myNewCoordinates` collection set up into `this.sketchCoords_` object.

I left this solution for people with similar problem. Maybe it'll help. If yes then upvote my ask and answer, please.